# Can't add 20px of padding on bottom of Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I've spent several hours try to figure out this darn thing.  If you go **[here](http://www.matthewkosloski.me/help/)**, and click on the image, a Fancybox w/ red overlay successfully pops up.  The problem is, when you scroll all the way down to the bottom, the Fancybox kisses the bottom of the browser, and there is no space.  I want there to be space there!

I've tried to add `bottom:20px;` or `padding: 0 0 20px 0;` to the `<div class="fancybox-wrap fancybox-desktop fancybox-type-image fancybox-opened"</div>` class; but got ZIP!

I really appreciate your time, and unlike me, I hope you can find the solution.

*P.S. — Sorry for the lack of a jsFiddle link.  Fancybox doesn't play well w/ jsFiddle. ;(*

Comment: Thanks man, cannot believe I didn't think of that...

Comment: OK, can I add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is quite simple, just add this line of CSS to `.fancybox-wrap fancybox-desktop fancybox-type-image fancybox-opened`:

```
margin-bottom:20px;
```

The CSS you tried to add would only give more space inside of the div, not outside it, which `margin` on the other hand does.